# Efficiently tracing the sum of sets from balanced subset sum?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Balanced subset sum problem is described as to divide array into two subsets such that difference of sum of two sub sets is minimum, Best case will be when sum of two subsets are equal.

**Note**: - We can not leave elements from the original set .

Now i need to **get the sum of set 1 and set 2** for the minimum difference partitioning, I have already found the sum of sets using a `O(sum*sum*n)` solution , but for the purpose of what I am doing i need something with a better complexity. How can this be solved in less time than `O(sum*sum*n)`?

My O(N^3) approach is as under:
Note : -s1,s2,s3 are static variables,sum being the sum of array.

```
static int partition(int sum1, int sum2, ArrayList < Integer > arr, int i) {
 if (i == arr.size()) {
  if (Math.abs(sum1 - sum2) < s3) {
   s1 = sum1;
   s2 = sum2;
   s3 = Math.abs(sum1 - sum2);
  }

  return Math.abs(sum1 - sum2);

 }
 if (dp[(sum1 < 0) ? 2 * sum - sum1 : sum1][(sum1 < 0) ? 2 * sum - sum1 : sum1][i] != 0)
  return dp[(sum1 < 0) ? 2 * sum - sum1 : sum1][(sum1 < 0) ? 2 * sum - sum1 : sum1][i] > 0 ? dp[(sum1 < 0) ? 2 * sum - sum1 : sum1][(sum1 < 0) ? 2 * sum - sum1 : sum1][i] - 1 : dp[(sum1 < 0) ? 2 * sum - sum1 : sum1][(sum1 < 0) ? 2 * sum - sum1 : sum1][i];


 int c1 = partition(sum1 +  arr.get(i), sum2, arr, i + 1);
 int c2 = partition(sum1, sum2 +  arr.get(i), arr, i + 1);

 if (Math.abs(c1) < Math.abs(c2)) {
  dp[(sum1 < 0) ? 2 * sum - sum1 : sum1][(sum1 < 0) ? 2 * sum - sum1 : sum1][i] = c1 >= 0 ? c1 + 1 : c1;
  return c1;
 } else {
  dp[(sum1 < 0) ? 2* sum - sum1 : sum1][(sum1 < 0) ? 2 * sum - sum1 : sum1][i] = c2 >= 0 ? c2 + 1 : c2;
  return c2;
 }

}
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem ?

Comment: @MBo yes ,this being a more generalistic case.

Comment: I don't claim to understand your code, but this is a NPC problem, so it would be a real surprise for a polynomial algorithm to solve it. So either your algorithm or your estimation of the running time are not wrong.

Comment: How big can the elements of `arr` be?

Comment: @ead elements are not exceeding 225 and maximum no. of elements are 20 .

Comment: @ead I incorrectly wrote the complexity earlier , it can be solved in `O(sum*sum*n)` .

Comment: With these sizes, a brute force O(2^n) solution may actually be faster than the smart DP algorithm.

Comment: @n.m. yes, realized that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use a [pseudo-polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-polynomial_time) algorithm which runs in `O(sum*n)`, albeit the proposal in comments to use `O(2^ n)` brute force approach should work as well.

The idea is similar to [pseudo-polynomial algorithm for knapsack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#0.2F1_knapsack_problem): find all possible partitions with combined value less or equal `MAX=sum/2`. The biggest of these partitions will be the one you are looking for.

Here is a possible implementation in python:

```
def min_partition_diff(items):
    summed=sum(items)
    MAX=summed//2


    value_reachable=[False]*(MAX+1)    
    value_reachable[0]=True #at the beginning only the empty set with value 0 is reachable

    #update all possible configurations:
    for item in items:
        for i in reversed(range(MAX)):# //backwards->object at most once in every configuration!
            if value_reachable[i]:#update configuration only if it can be constructed with earlier items
               next_reachable_value = i+item
               if next_reachable_value <= MAX:
                    value_reachable[next_reachable_value]=True

    biggest_value_possible=MAX - value_reachable[::-1].index(True)# find last True in the values

    return summed-2*biggest_value_possible # this is the smallest difference
```